# MySQL group by - is not working on server?

Tags: mysql

We just upgraded mysql and the group by function is not working on the server.  Is there something I can set to allow it to work?

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      civicrm_relationship 
   where 
          contact_id_a = '$contactid' 
      and (   relationship_type_id = 5 
           or relationship_type_id = 22) 
      and is_active = 1 
   GROUP BY 
      contact_id_b
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that GROUP BY doesn't work. Have you tried an independent test of this query with known values that should give expected/known results?

Comment: I removed the group by from the query and it worked. anytime there is a group by in and it fails and there is no error.

Comment: Usually you must group by with a list of fields for grouping. And usually you must have some aggregate function (sum, count, etc). MySql does have some feature for "automatically" doing things with group by fields. I don't know MySql very well. Probably with your upgrade you have changed that setting. In general, your query is not good sql by standard sql rules.

Comment: Does https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that is the setting -- `only_full_group_by`

Comment: By "not working", does it mean it returns nothing, or does it tell you there is an error?